# By elements and IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium

Could you explain the difference between `By` element and `IWebElement`s.

Also, why doesn't selenium use one or the other?

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@class='example']/h3")] 
private IWebElement _heading;
```

and

```
var byElement = By.XPath("//div[@class='example']/h3")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IWebElement` is a selenium Web Element class which *represents an HTML element* (`body`, `table`, `tr` etc) on a page in your selenium automation code. Through the `IWebElement` instance, you can interact with an element, retrieve it's attributes and properties.

`By.something()` is just a *locator* - the way you tell selenium how to locate the element within the document so that you can make an `IWebElement` instance. The are different built-in locators, like `By.Xpath`, `By.CssSelector`, `By.Id` etc.